# SQL Delete Tables within a specific Range

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have a MySQL database with 20.000 tables. All tables going like
table1
table2
...
table20000

Is there a sql code to delete tables within a specific range? Or is there a easy way?

I have searched internet but I couldn't find a way. It would be much easier if there was code or easy way instead deleting table just one by one. Thanks everyone.

Comment: You need Dynamic SQL

Comment: @lad2025 I just want to delete those tables if there is easy way

Comment: Build with PHP simple script `DROP TABLE [variable]` ,run inside loop and set variable to needed value, this is very simple string concatenation thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. create a PHP script
2. use information_schema.tables or 'show tables' to dynamically find your table names
3. select a range (from the user or in some variables)
4. loop and do the DROP TABLE